# Trying to return integer value through conditional statements results in error

Tags: java

I was just finishing up an assignment and I keep running into an error with the code below. "This method must return a result of type int." From the research I have done this is due to the compiler requires a default return value even it if is impossible to reach it, however if I do so, it conflicts with the method that calls the method below. Furthermore, I also ran across a post where it was suggested to throw and exception which I did try, however, it did not bring me any luck.

```
public int CompareTo(HugeInteger h) {
    if(h.HugeInteger.length() > this.HugeInteger.length()) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if(h.HugeInteger.length() < this.HugeInteger.length()) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(h.HugeInteger == this.HugeInteger) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < h.HugeInteger.length(); i++) {
            if(h.HugeInteger.charAt(i) > this.HugeInteger.charAt(i)) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if(h.HugeInteger.charAt(i) < this.HugeInteger.charAt(i)) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Something just went really wrong.....");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Your for loop will never be executed more than once

Comment: It’s very simple, in the method declaration you have stated that your method returns an int so you must deliver on that promise. If you want to throw an exception do it at the very end outside of any loops or if/else clause

Comment: @Snowy_1803 I just realized that, and remove the throw. However, the issue still remains.

Comment: What happens if the two instances are equal, without being the same instance ?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Alright, that makes sense, I just thought of a way to implement the method with a default return, thank you!!

Comment: @Snowy_1803 The 2nd elseif statement should take care of that no?

Comment: Show your code without the `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator checks for instance equality. If you have two instances of the class with same data, it will return false.

Even if you use the `equals` method, the compiler detects that the method can end without a return type if the for loop is not executed (or if all characters are the same, if you remove your `throw` statement). Therefore, you must put a `return` or `throw` statement at the end of your method.

To solve your problem, you should add `return 0;` at the end of your method, as it would be reached if the two instances are equal.

Comment: That is not why this compiler error happens though.

Comment: The error happens because the compiler thinks the method can end without a return type, as said in the comments. It may be unclear in my answer...

Comment: And that has nothing to do with the `==` vs `.equals`, so your answer makes no sense.

Comment: I was answering to the OP's last comment.

Comment: The problem only has to do with structural analysis done by the compiler. The loop body of a for loop may execute **0** or more times given the code shown (`length()` could be zero as far as the compiler is concerned), so there is an execution path that does not return a value nor ends abruptly (throws an exception) as it never enters the loop body.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify that

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Does it still deserve a downvote?